# How do numpy block matrices work?

Tags: python, numpy

The outcome of this code doesn't make any sense to me:

```
a = np.zeros((2, 2))
b = np.bmat([[a, a], [a, a]])
print(b.shape, b.dot(np.zeros(4)).shape)
```

How can a matrix with shape `(4, 4)` when doing a sum-product over its final axis return a matrix of shape `(1, 4)`?

Comment: `bmat` returns a *matrix*, as in those things you should never use. Make an array: `b = np.bmat([[a, a], [a, a]]).A`.

Comment: @user2357112 Oh!! That's it.  Please add an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bmat` returns a `numpy.matrix` instance, as in those things you should never use because they cause all kinds of weird incompatibilities. `numpy.matrix` always tries to preserve at least two dimensions, so `b.dot(np.zeros(4))` is 2D instead of 1D.

Make a `numpy.array`:

```
b = np.bmat([[a, a], [a, a]]).A
#                             ^
```

Or as of NumPy 1.13,

```
b = np.block([[a, a], [a, a]])
```

Comment: @NeilG: I see an `np.block` in the dev repository, but not in any current release. Did you intend to refer to an unreleased function?

Comment: @NeilG: It is? Huh. I guess the docs haven't been updated yet.

Answer (score 1):

`bmat` doesn't do anything exotic or fancy; basically it's just a couple  of levels on concatenation:

```
In [308]: np.bmat([[a,a],[a,a]]).A
Out[308]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 1],
       [2, 3, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 0, 1],
       [2, 3, 2, 3]])

In [309]: alist = [[a,a],[a,a]]
In [310]: np.concatenate([np.concatenate(sublist, axis=1) for sublist in alist], axis=0)
Out[310]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 1],
       [2, 3, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 0, 1],
       [2, 3, 2, 3]])
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't find the second version readable at all!

Comment: Is `np.vstack((np.hstack((a, a)), np.hstack((a, a))))` any clearer?  My point is that internally, `bmat` is just a bunch of concatenates.

Comment: Oh, I see, you're answering "how do block matrices work?"  Gotcha.